# Command to make player wear skeleton head

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a map where you get chased by another player and I want the killer to be invisible (already figured that out) and I want him to wear a skeleton head.

How do I do that with command blocks?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 0):

To equip the head, simply enter
 “/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head 0 skull”
Make sure that the killer is the closest one to the command block when this command executes.